# Dynamically assign the text content of a certain day in react-native-calendars

Tags: react-native

eg. when I click the date “ March, 7th ” ，the text “21 days” will appear on 21 days later date in calendar instead of "March，28th”.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You probably should create a new Day Component for what you need.

1. You can create a new Day Component inside the react native calendar: react-native-calendars/src/calendar/day/
2. You can create a new Day Component using the API of the react native calendar, check the documentation for it here https://github.com/wix/react-native-calendars#overriding-day-component:

   dayComponent={({date, state}) => {
       return (customDayComponent);
     }}

Or without day component you will have to get the left and top position of the needed day and place an overlaying View over the day (position: 'absolute', zIndex: 1).

Comment: thx!  I simply solved the problem ：https://xinwei.bitcron.com/post/react-native-calendars-dong-tai-zhi-ding-mou-tian-xian-shi-de-wen-zi-nei-rong